# Como ejecutar una sentencia sql con un bucle for para registrar varias filas en un solo registro en java?

Tags: java, mysql, mvc, bucle-for, depuración

Pongo en contexto, en mi sistema de agendamiento de citas quiero registrar un array en una tabla, esta tabla aloja los id de una cita y los id de los diversos servicios que el usuario puede elegir para esta cita, hay otra columna que puede ser null sin ningún problema aquella tabla tiene como nombre cita_Servicio, las columnas que contiene esta tabla son idCita y idServicio quiere decir que una cita puedo tener muchos servicios por este motivo necesito registrar varios registros a la vez a continuación agrego código

```
public class CitaServicioDAO extends Conexion implements Crud {
//1.Declarar objetos y variables

private Connection conexion = null;
private PreparedStatement puente = null;
private ResultSet mensajero = null;

//1.1.Declarar variable para cualquier metodo
public boolean operaciones = false;
public String sql;

//1.2.Declarar las variables del VO
public String idCita="", idServicio[];
public String cisCosto = "";

public CitaServicioDAO() {
}

//2.
public CitaServicioDAO(CitaServicioVO cisVO) {
    super();

    try {
        conexion = this.obtenerConexion();
        idCita = cisVO.getIdCita();
        idServicio = cisVO.getIdServicio();
        cisCosto = cisVO.getCisCosto();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(CitaServicioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean agregarRegistro() {
    try {
        sql = "INSERT INTO cita_servicio VALUES(?,?)";
            puente = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);            
        for (int i = 0; i < idServicio.length; i++) {
            puente.setString(1, idCita);
            puente.setString(2, idServicio[i]);
            puente.addBatch();
            puente.executeBatch();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(CitaServicioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    } finally {
        try {
            this.cerrarConexion();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(CitaServicioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
    return operaciones;
}
```

Realmente no se cual es el problema aqui, no se por que no me registra en la base de datos hago debug y continuación los pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de yo hacer debug todo correcto pero me salta el try catch a la expeption y cada variable toma su valor correspondiente quisiera saber cual es el error no logro encontrarlo,Agradeceria respuesta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Linea 63

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Linea 64

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Linea 68 lo que dice el exception e

Comment: Cual es el error que te tira?

Comment: Por eso digo salta a la exception como esta amrcado en la imagen en verde
lo que tiene que pasar es que debe saltar al metodo cerrarConexion y no me registra  en la base de datos

Comment: Si salta a la exception es porque hay un error, mi pregunta es cual es ese error?

Comment: Amigo por eso estoy preguntando jajaja es que no se que pasa, no se si falta algo o que

Comment: Amigo mira las imágenes que acabo de colocar de lo que pasa en cada linea de código realizando debug tal vez ahi encuentres el error

Comment: un `e.getMessage` o `e.printStackTrace` en ese Logger pa saber cuál es el error, porque sí, cae en el catch, pero necesitas (necesitamos) ver qué dice ese `e`. Añade eso y mira la salida del logger a ver qué dice

Comment: Pense que ya lo habia colocado, pero ya ahora si puedes ver lo que dice la e

Comment: El problema posiblemente está en los datos que espera tu tabla `cita_servicio`. ¿Podrías añadir, por favor, la definición de esa tabla? Puede que haya un campo not null que no estés entregando

Comment: Te explico, esta tabla aloja los id de una cita y los id de los diversos servicios que el usuario puede elegir  para esta cita, hay otra columna que puede ser null sin ningun problema

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade la info adicional. Si volvemos los comentarios un chat, los que tengan el mismo problema en el futuro no sabrán tan fácil si es el mismo problema. Usa siempre el enlace `editar` justo bajo la pregunta y le añades la info. PD. La mejor forma de explicarnos cómo está definida la tabla es poniendo la definición de la tabla en la pregunta. Campos y tipos de dato, índices y PK si la hay. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La instrucción `executeBatch()` se ejecuta UNA vez, cuando terminas de añadir todos los conjuntos de valores.

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < idServicio.length; i++) {
    puente.setString(1, idCita);
    puente.setString(2, idServicio[i]);
    puente.addBatch();
}
puente.executeBatch();
...
```

Lo otro: yo revisaría (no sé si lo haces en otro lugar) que el elemento en idServicio no esté vacío para ningún caso.

Comment: Mira hize eso y pues ahora si me recorre correctamente el bucle for pero sigue con el mismo problema, exception e me manda el mismo error

Comment: @DavidSepulveda Ya cerraste la pregunta duplicada?

Comment: ya la borre amigo

Comment: amigo ahora que hago, no entiendo por que pasa eso

Comment: Añade la definición completa de la tabla a la pregunta, porfa. Estoy casi seguro que por ahí va la cosa (falla en el primer registro teniendo datos).

Comment: Amigo ya encontre el problema, muchas gracias fue algo bobo pero bueno de esto se aprende, muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solucion del problema

```
 public boolean agregarRegistro() {
    try {
        sql = "INSERT INTO cita_servicio (idCita, idServicio) VALUES(?,?)";
            puente = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);            
        for (int i = 0; i < idServicio.length; i++) {
            puente.setString(1, idCita);
            puente.setString(2, idServicio[i]);
            puente.addBatch();               
        }
            puente.executeBatch();
            operaciones = true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(CitaServicioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    } finally {
        try {
            this.cerrarConexion();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(CitaServicioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
    return operaciones;
}
```